# Woocommerce Listable add to cart adding 2 quantity

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Listable theme from themeforest and it has listing pages. Below listing, there is Add to Cart button, whenever I click that. It adds 2 quantity in the cart.

Suppose I have 0 quantity, it will add 2 quantity of selected product to cart. if I have 2 quantity and I add to cart again, I get 4 quantity.

The piece of code I was able to track down is this:

```
WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $_POST['add-to-cart'],$_POST['quantity']);
ob_clean();
ob_start();
wp_redirect( "http://website.com/cart/" ); 
exit();
```

Above code works on the POST request only. I tried to change to something like this:

```
$_product_id = $_POST['add-to-cart'];
$_cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();

$_found_item = false;

if( count($cart_items) > 0 ){

    foreach ($cart_items as $value) {

        if( $value->product_id == $product_id )
        {
            $_found_item = true;
            break;
        }

    }

    if(!$_found_item){
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $_product_id );
    }

}else{
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $_product_id );
}
wp_redirect( "http://website.com/cart/" ); 
exit();
```

But still, on cart page, it updates quantity by 2 every time. I want to fix this to add 1 quantity at a time. Is there something else I should look in the code?

Comment: Are this code just like this?… It isn't hooked in some function with an add_action? This code is really strange. You should contact theme authors support pages and open a ticket… as it's a premium theme.